# Cross-browser confusion: absolute positioning, display: block and jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi Everyone: I have a "help button" that I want on the top right of my page. My help button is an image with a link, and I have used jQuery to change the image on hover. I put the image class inside the link class, and the link class inside an absolutely positioned div.

It works like a charm in IE, but in Firefox, Safari and Chrome, there is no link and the image doesn't change. I suspect I have screwed up the positioning maybe, but how?

I'm just a beginner at this, so please explain like I'm five, if you could. And I don't know what's relevant, so here's the whole dirty business. Thanks so much for any help you can give me!

CSS

```
#help-me {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 169px;
    width: 225px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.help-button {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px pink solid;
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
}
.rollover {
    border: 1px black dashed;
    height: 169px;
    width: 225px;
}
```

HTML and jQuery

```
<div id="help-me">
    <a href="#" class="help-button"><img src="ticket-bubble_off.gif" class="rollover"/>&nbsp;</a>
</div>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"    type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img.rollover").hover( 
        function() { this.src = this.src.replace("_off", "_on"); }, 
        function() { this.src = this.src.replace("_on", "_off"); }
    );
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/85u13sg3/

Comment: But not for me! Perhaps I didn't give you all the relevant mark-up? What else do you think I might have done to screw it up?

Comment: Try to reproduce the issue in demo, otherwise it's not possible to help.

Comment: OK, how do I reproduce the issue in demo? I'm sorry, I'm *really* new to this.